# Changing date format in a cell in a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, date, format

I am relatively new to R and I need my date and time in a specific format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) within the same cell and currently it is in DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM. Please may I ask if anyone knows how I can do this within R?

I have put a small snippet of my dataframe below:

```
  DateTime       Depth  Temp
18/07/2010 12:00  0.00  22.2
18/07/2010 12:00  0.50  21.1
18/07/2010 12:00  1.00  21.8
18/07/2010 12:00  1.50  22.8
18/07/2010 12:00  2.00  22.0
18/07/2010 12:00  2.50  19.7
18/07/2010 12:00  3.00  16.6
18/07/2010 12:00  3.50  12.5
18/07/2010 12:00  4.00   9.3
18/07/2010 12:00  4.50   7.6
```

I have attempted the following lines of code and they either produce errors or NA values.

```
fdata1<-format(as.Date(fdata$DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y/%H/%M"),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
fdata1<-order(fdata$DateTime, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
fdata1<- as.Date(fdata$DateTime, format = "%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M") - produces lots of NA values
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(DateTime = c("18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", 
                              "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", 
                              "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00", "18/07/2010 12:00"
  ),
  Depth = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5),
  Temp = c(22.2,21.1, 21.8, 22.8, 22, 19.7, 16.6, 12.5, 9.3, 7.6)), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

### Tidyverse approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    DateTime = dmy_hms(DateTime),
    DateTime = format(DateTime,format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
    )
```

### Base approach

```
   df$DateTime <- format(as.POSIXct(df$DateTime,format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```